# De-Dupe Query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access to create a report.  I have several duplicate records in my Avail_Amt field.  I used the Query Wizard to de-dup records from a table, like this.

```
In (SELECT [DEALLOCALBAL] FROM [TBL_DATA] As Tmp GROUP BY [DEALLOCALBAL] HAVING Count(*)=1 )
```

What I really want to do, though, is de-dupe the records in my Query, not in my Table.  I think it should look like the script below, but it's not working.

```
In (SELECT [DEALLOCALBAL] FROM [dbo_LIMIT_HIST.Avail_Amt] As Tmp GROUP BY [DEALLOCALBAL] HAVING Count(*)=1 )
```

`dbo_LIMIT_HIST` is the Table in SQL Server and `Avail_Amt` is the Field that I am trying to de-dupe.  Any idea what could be wrong here?

My data set looks like this:
[image]

Basically, for each Contact ID I could have multiple DEALLOCALBAL amounts.  I want to capture each unique amount for each Contact ID, but I don't want dupes.

Thanks!!

Comment: An `IN` seems like an unlikely route to de-duplication.  Sample data and desired results would clarify your question.

Comment: @ryguy72:  Where you have `[dbo_LIMIT_HIST.Avail_Amt]` should be just `[dbo_LIMIT_HIST]` because a `FROM` is looking for just the table name.  And if you want it to group by `[Avail_Amt]`, you need to put that in the `GROUP BY` section where you currently have `[DEALLOCALBAL]`.

Comment: Why are there duplicates? Is this dataset the result of a query? Are there more fields not showing? The dataset does not show Avail_Amt field. The third record in the dataset is not a duplicate. Is DEALLOCALBAL missing a 0?